# EF Core add-migration target postgreeSQL return Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core

i try to use Add-Migration init_postgreeDB -Context 'ApplicationDbContext'
target data base postgree
installet nuget

- [image]

full returned error

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.NpgsqlServiceCollectionExtensions.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Infrastructure.Internal.NpgsqlOptionsExtension.ApplyServices(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.ApplyServices(IDbContextOptions options, ServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.<GetOrAdd>g__BuildServiceProvider|4_1(IDbContextOptions _, ValueTuple`2 arguments)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.<>c.<GetOrAdd>b__4_0(IDbContextOptions contextOptions, ValueTuple`2 tuples)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd[TArg](TKey key, Func`3 valueFactory, TArg factoryArgument)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.GetOrAdd(IDbContextOptions options, Boolean providerRequired)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext..ctor(DbContextOptions options)
   at DigitalBanking.Administration.Infrastructure.ApplicationDbContext..ctor(DbContextOptions`1 options) in C:\EPL-Projects\Digital\New Digital Administration panel\Updated-Backend\DigitalBanking.Administration\Infrastructure\ApplicationDbContext.cs:line 12
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass21_3.<FindContextTypes>b__11()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

i can not to understand returned error so if one can help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because the 7.0.0 version of Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL package is not released yet you have to use the 7.0.0-rc.2 pre-release version to support .NET 7.0 until the full release of Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 7.0.0

Comment: i downgrade to version 6.0.2 and it working fine

Comment: Sure but the issue here was a mismatch between Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory version 7.0.0 and Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL given the timing as the full 7.0.0 version of the latter package had not released yet :-)

Comment: This answer is now obsolete because the version in question has been released. If you are having this problem, just make sure to upgrade your Npgsql package to match.